# Android GoogleMaps overlay with parallelogram/rhomboid image

Tags: android, image, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am developing an Android map based application which overlay a different information on the map. I have problem with overlaying an image. I would like to fit image which is distributed in normal orthogonal shape to custom coordinates which mostly set a parallelogram/rhomboid shape. Following url with screenshot present problem:

[Example screenshot of map with image and footprint GroundOverlay](http://i59.tinypic.com/2rortrt.png)

and here is an code of my image overlay:

```
BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap);

GroundOverlayOptions groundOverlay = new GroundOverlayOptions()
    .image(image)
    .position(qLookCenter, qLookWidth, qLookHeight)
    .bearing(qLookBearing)
    .zIndex(2)
    .transparency((float) 0.35);

mMap.addGroundOverlay(groundOverlay);
```

The image should be fitted to the blue footprint. GroundOverlay provide only resizing and rotating an overlaid image but not allow to **warp image**. Is any solution to make this kind if image manipulation? I will be grateful for any piece of code or any idea.

Comment: Please share any code you have attempted thus far, or at least the code framework that is holding the map.

Comment: I added a groundoverlay code but it not allow to warp image and I do not have any idea to do this. Probably it will be a way to fit image to the footprint or to coordinates of corner.